# React-Redux: getState() not available

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I've encountered this really frustrating issue with redux and `getState()`. I have this async thunk:

```js
export const getUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch(requestCurrentUser());
    const user = await apiService.getUser();
    console.log(user);
    debugger;
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(failureCurrentUser(e));
  }
};
```

The debugger activates, as it should, but `getState()` is not defined, only `dispatch()`. What is weird is that if I step through the call stack and land on the first line `export const getUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {`, `getState` is defined there but for some reason, when the function starts executing, it becomes unavailable.

If it is of any importance - I'm calling `getUser()` in the root file of the project, in a `useEffect()` like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(getCurrentUser());
  }, []);
```

I have to call it via `store` since this root component renders the `<Provider />`.

Also, I'm using redux-toolkit and now migrating gradually from pure redux, hence the action.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How did you set up the redux store? And the action creator is `getUser`, you are dispatching the `getCurrentUser`. Your code can't run, so can't help. After creating a mvce, try to narrow down the issue

Comment: This could be because the js code is optimized to remove unused variables from scope, try to use `getState` in `getUser` somewhere.

Comment: Can't believe it... Thanks, @HMR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devtools will remove unused variables from scope, when you run the below code in console and at the debugger breakpoint try to access `value` you'll get `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined` error.

```
function test (value){
  console.log('value is fine here:',value);
  return function something(){
   //here try to console log value in the console
   debugger;
   return 88
  }
}
test(22)()
```

So in your code you can just use `getState` and it will not be removed after optimization:

```
export const getUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    //using getState here so it won't be removed from scope
    console.log(getState);
    dispatch(requestCurrentUser());
    const user = await apiService.getUser();
    console.log(user);
    debugger;
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(failureCurrentUser(e));
  }
};
```